# How can I create an imageview rotate 360° infinity and smoothly in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, rotation, imageview, geometry

After spending at least an hour searching for a solution, I have been unsuccessful. I am very new to XCode and Swift so I am struggling to understand what some of the more experienced people are meaning along with the fact that a lot of the answers are outdated.

How can I create an imageView rotate 360° infinity and smoothly in Swift?

Comment: Go through some tutorial, try something and ask a specific question here. Stack Overflow is not meant for broad questions

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn how to ask better questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are referring to iOS, where every view is layer-backed. That makes it very easier to add visual effects.

To start animation:

```
let rotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
rotation.byValue = 2 * CGFloat.pi // measured in radians. positive = clockwise, negative = counter-clockwise
rotation.duration = 2
rotation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude // forever

imageView.layer.add(rotation, forKey: "myAnimation")
```

To end animation:

```
imageView.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "myAnimation")
// or:
imageView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Adjust to taste!

Answer (score -2):

You cannot rotate an image by 360 degrees—since it will end up in the same spot, it will not appear to move.

So, use [the same method for rotating as Code Different showed you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45683494/366904), but instead rotate the image 359 degrees. Then, when it finishes rotating, rotate it again to complete the final degree. This should look very smooth.

Comment: I assumed you tested my answer and found that it didn't work?